# NullPointerException double linked list

Tags: java, eclipse, list, linked-list, double

after looking through the threads i found that the NullPointerException is quite typical but also very specific for every Code.

I tried different suggestion but no one was the right one for me. 
I want to build a double linked list and the pointer of the last listelement should direct to a "null" element, like this example.

[DVL Wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDoubly-linked-list.svg)

I hope that you can give me a clue why i get the NullPointerException:

```
private IListElement current, prev, next;
private IValueElement dummy = new ValueElement("Head", 0);
private IListElement head = new ListElement(dummy);
private IValueElement wert;


public void deleteAllOf(IValueElement value)
{
    current=head;
    count = 0;

    for(i=0;i==numNodes;i++)
    {

        next=current.getSuccessor();
        current=next;
        wert = current.getValueElement();

        if(wert == value)
        {
            prev = current.getPredecessor();
            next = current.getSuccessor();

            next.setPredecessor(prev);
            prev.setSuccessor(next);
            count+=1;
        }

    }
    numNodes= numNodes-count;
}
```

For the error Code:

> StackTrace    java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   implementierung.List.deleteFirstOf(List.java:178) at
>   testklassen.TestsList.testDeleteFirstOf(TestsList.java:572) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:14)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:66)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:1)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:166)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$0(ParentRunner.java:164) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:159) at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:204) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:146) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:123) at
>   unittestenvironment.TestRunner.addTestGroup(TestRunner.java:210) at
>   unittestenvironment.TestRunnerForMetis.main(TestRunnerForMetis.java:54)

Comment: I do not understand how your for-loop works??
It says:

   [for i = 0, as long i is equal to numNodes, increment i]

Num-node does not change inside your loop, so the loop is executed once (if numnodes is 0, else it is executed never) maybe this is your problem...

Comment: Look at the header of your `for` loop. `i==numNodes;`?

Comment: The stack trace says the NPE occurs at line 178 in the `deleteFirstOf` method. Can you post that method, please?

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Several hiccups....

1. First declare `int i` in the for condition. Its a  good practice, instead of declaring `int i` in the beginning and using it in the entire program.
2. `for(int i=0;i==numNodes;i++)`.... You are looping till `i==numNodes` so the last node will have its next pointer to null. so `null->next` will give you `NullPointerException`.

It should be  `for(int i=0; i<numNodes; i++)`

Comment: The for loop should be for(int i=0;i<numNodes;i++)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others the for loop needs to be fixed. I actually suspect that this is not the cause of your null pointer exception however. As far as I can tell the deleteAllof method you've posted shouldn't do much of anything, (the for loop will only execute if numNodes == 0, that is if the list is empty to begin with). The stack trace you posted indicates that the NullPointerException occurred in a different method, deleteFirstOF, which you did not post.

I have a suspicion from your comments that you are trying to access the final null element of the list. It is not possible to be sure how or why since the relevant code is not posted. Just be sure that you are not counting the null in the length of your list and that when iterating though your list you stop at i < length, if you begin at i=0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only get in the loop if numNodes == 0, I suspect you are getting the null pointer exception at this step:

```
 wert = current.getValueElement();
```

What you are missing is that eventually you will reach the end of the list and the current node will not have a successor.  You need to test for the case where the next node in your list is null.  However as others have said, learn to use a debugger and learn to take a hard look at the specific lines of code called out in the exception stack traces.